# Inheritance and methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor

I'm having a problem with the constructors of classes and sub-classes(that extend the first class)

This is the basic class's constructor:

```
    public Airplane(int x, int y, int width)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        createSeats();
    }
```

And here is another class's constructor that extends the basic class

```
public Boeing(int x, int y, int width)
{
    super(x,y,width);
    createSeats();
}
```

The problem is that `createSeats()` is another method in both classes, but `Boeing` has to override the main one. How can I make it so that this will work without taking the `createSeats()` method out?

Comment: If you have created a new method `createSeats()` in Boeing, then it will override the one from `Airplane`. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Why won't it work the way you have it?

Comment: Doesn't calling super(x,y,width) call createSeats(); in the constructor as well?

Comment: @ JA3N: try with simple System.out.print ...

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want all subclasses of `Airplane` to call `createSeats()` on construction then you can leave the call in the `Airplane` constructor and remove from `Boeing`.

If you only want particular subclasses, e.g. `Boeing` to call `createSeats()` on construction then you can leave the call in the `Boeing` constructor and remove from `Airplane`.

You **don't** need the invocations in both constructors, leaving them there will result in `createSeats()` being called twice for each `Boeing` you initialise.

Comment: All classes and sub-classes need the createSeats() method, it's that the createSeats() method in Boeing is overriding the method in Airplane

Comment: If that's the case then remove it from the subclass constructor. The overriding method will be invoked in the superclass constrictor.

Comment: @JA3N That's fine.  Calling `Airplane.createSeats()` will call `Boeing.createSeats()` if it's been overridden by `Boeing`.  So the effect will be the same.  See my answer if you want to call `Airplane.createSeats()` from the overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

The call to the super constructor already includes the call to the createSeats() method, so you don't have to reinclude it in the Boeing constructor.

If you only want to change the behavior of creating seats, just override that method.

```
class Airplane {
  public Airplane(int x, int y, int width)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    createSeats();
  }

  void createSeats() { /* create them */ }
}
class Boeing {
  public Boeing(int x, int y, int width)
  {
    super(x,y,width); // same steps as super class
  }

  @Override
  void createSeats()
  {
    // do something else entirely
    // possibly call super.createSeats()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Frequently a default implementation of a method is provided in a super class, which allows you to customize the behavior in a subclass by overriding the method in a subclass. E.g. Does an **Airplane** know how to create seats on a **Boeing**? Probably not, therefore you would **override** the **createSeats**() in your subclass to provide the specific implementation that works for you particular type of **Airplane**.

The fact that the **createSeats**() method is called from inside your super class' constructor guarantees that the method in question will always be called on construction of the object. This is a common design pattern. It's called template method. Basically you have a method that encapsulates the execution of a number of methods in a certain order to produce an outcome. In your case there's one method namely **createSeats**().

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @milkplusvellocet's answer, however you also said "The problem is that createSeats() is another method in both classes, but Boeing has to override the main one."  If you ever need to call a superclass's method instead of your own, you can always call `super.createSeats()`.  That way you can always differentiate between methods in the superclass and your own methods.

However, that said, that's almost always used in the method you're overriding.  For example,

```
@Override
public void createSeats() {
  doSomethingSpecial();
  super.createSeats();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

@Override

before the method you want to override should do the job

Comment: That just provides a compile-time check that the annotated method overrides some superclass method. It does not change behaviour in any way.